# How to serialize and deserialize hierarchical class as xml in C#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, hierarchy, xml-deserialization

Actually I could serialize but i couldn't deserialize it. I need to have an object of my viewmodel with all children from output of destabilization and also i'm not sure where i should set my xml attributes; model or view model.

Here's my clss and viewmodel

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }       
     readonly List<Person> children = new List<Person>();
     public IList<Person> Children
     {
         get { return children; }
     }    
}

public class PersonViewModel : {

private ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> children; 
private Person person;

public PersonViewModel()
{
    person = new Person();
}

public PersonViewModel(Person _person)
{
    person = _person;
    children = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>(
            (from child in _person.Children
                select new PersonViewModel(child))
                .ToList<PersonViewModel>());
}

[XmlElement("Name", typeof(string))]
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return person.Name;
    }

    set
    {
        person.Name = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}

[XmlArray("Children", IsNullable = false), XmlArrayItem("Person"),]
public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Children
{
    get
    {
        return children;
    }
}
```

}

this is the content of xml file that my code generated already.
but when i want to deserilize it to an object type of my view model, the children won't initialized by existing data.

[image]

Serializer:

```
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonViewModel), new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "OrgChart" });
        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OrgChart.XML"))
        {
            xs.Serialize(wr, rootPerson);
        }
```

Deserializer:

```
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonViewModel), new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "OrgChart" });

                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

                rootPerson = SelectedItem = Profile = (PersonViewModel)xs.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase "output of destabilization"? The XmlSerializer can serialize/deserialize the public read/writable surface of a class. Since children has no setter it cannot be deserialized.

Comment: I would like to add that only class properties can be serialized or deserialized. Person class (you are going to serialize Person, aren't you?) contains IList<Children> but have to contain List<Children> with getter and setter. I believe that readonly children field have not to be a readonly because deserializer will create Person object and assign new value to Childern property. Could you please show your serialize/deserialize code?

Comment: thanks, I just updated my post and added the outcome of my xmlsterilizer. Yes, i want to serialize the person class. but when i want to deserialize the xml file i need and object of my view model.

Comment: @Ralf, Oleksa; Thank you so much for the help, I got it.